# How to find which of my google sheet scripts have any timed trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I have many projects,some of them very very larg (covid-19 related research) a few with timed triggers.  Over time, I have made copies of scripts, renamed, and continued with the copy, adding timed triggers.  I know I need to delete the triggers from the discontinued (but archived previously running) version of the script.  But occasionally I would forget.

Is there a way for me to search my drive among all the google sheets and lists all those which have any timed triggers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Drive.Files.list();` to find all of your project files.

GS:

```
function getScriptNamesTheHaveTimeBasedTriggerInCurrentProject() {
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().map(t => {
    if (t.getEventType() == ScriptApp.EventType.CLOCK) {
      return t.getHandlerFunction();
    }
  }).filter(e => e).join(','));
}
```

If you had a script like this inside of each project you might be able to execute it from App Script API but  you would have to select some external location to store the final output.  I'm not a 100% sure that it would work because I've never tried it.   In my case I have about 700 projects but I hardly ever you triggers so I don't have any real interest in attempting such a thing.

Comment: Cooper, thanks.  When I put the above function in a script file which has triggered function, it shows that function name on running your script.

Comment: Ok, DriveApp.getFiles() returns the list of file objects, and .next() will get the next in the list...  How do I retireve the script file name of a project, also test if a script exists?

Comment: I wouldn't be using  DriveApp at all.  I didn't suggest that.  I suggested using Drive API.  You can pick which kind of files you want in the query.

Comment: Cooper, a sample please... Thank you!